# Mircophone very quiet

Tags: windows-10, microphone, microsoft-teams, zoom-meeting

My Microphone is very quiet, not matter if I use it in a Zoom call or for recording.

I already maxed the mic boost:
[Microphone Boost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1hr2.png)

My drivers are up to date.

Is there any way to force windows to boost the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem some time ago...

I was able to solve it with Equalizer APO - https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo

Set the amplification for your device - it is permanently active then.